# Oracle DB Programmer: How to identify double byte character data in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, utf-8, internationalization

Hi Oracle sql programmers, how do you identify double byte character in the db which I mean to find all the data in column 1 in table1 which contain double byte character such as Chinese character(s)?

UPDATE 1: I don't even know what Chinese characters would be in the column, I just need to find all the first_name and last_name columns which users entered any non-English characters, then change the value to NA.

Comment: What is the database and national character set?  What is the data type of the column?

Comment: Hi, oracle 11gR2, AL16UTF16, and data type of the column is varchar2(50), thx!

Comment: AL16UTF16 is not a valid database character set.  I'll wager that is your national character set-- that controls how data in `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR2` columns are encoded.  If your column is a `VARCHAR2`, what is your database character set?

Comment: ordinary character set is AL32UTF8

Comment: To be blunt, if you don't want multibyte characters, why do you have a multibyte character set in your database?

Comment: Why would you want to prevent internationalization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest option assuming you truly mean non-English (i.e. *any* character not in the US7ASCII character set) would be something like

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET first_name = 'NA'
 WHERE length( first_name ) != lengthb( first_name )
```

`LENGTH` returns the length of a string in characters while `LENGTHB` returns the length of a string in bytes.  UTF-8 encodes the US7ASCII characters with a single byte.  If there are any non-US7SACII characters, the length in bytes will be greater than the length in characters.

Comment: whoaa, that is very smart, but when I tested it, the output data set is not just including those Chinese characters value for the first_name column, it also includes French characters such as o with the little dash mark on top of it in the value of first_name column. So my question is, are those french characters also double byte character since my boss only told me to get rid of double byte values such as Chinese characters, he didn't mention those french char though, do you know? we are so close! thx!

Comment: @magqq - Yes, French and other Western European characters will require more than one byte of storage in the UTF-8 character set.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this, but I guess you could convert each character to a number and look for values over 256:

```
SQL> select ascii(unistr('\53f0')) from dual;

ASCII(UNISTR('\53F0'))
----------------------
                 21488
```